# Android KERN_DEBUG Log Levels

Tags: android, linux-kernel, printk

Where are KERN_DEBUG log levels written to in Android? If I were, for example, to call

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "666 The beast lives here 666");
```

then where is the output written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In Android, output of printk can be read with

```
    $ adb shell cat /proc/kmsg
```

or, provided a prior log was written to before, then with

```
    $ adb shell /proc/last_kmsg
```

or with

```
    $ adb shell dmesg
```